# Jmeter gRPC sampler is throwing error : Proto folder path is empty

Tags: jmeter

While using Jmeter gRPC sampler getting error while listing the methods, though I have browsed the proper proto folder. Error : Proto folder path is empty. Please select your proto folder.

Please check [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0hfP.png)

@Dmitri T

Comment: The plugin outdated for 2 years.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/19638395/tringuyen @TriNguyen So you mean that we cannot use Jmeter grpc plugin anymore ?

Comment: It's not that you cannot use, but it's been a long time without any update. Also, that plugin does not support streaming gRPC. If your API is streaming type, then consider using other tool.

Answer (score 0):

So what? I'm getting the same error as well if the folder I specify doesn't contain the files the [gRPS plugin](https://github.com/zalopay-oss/jmeter-grpc-plugin?tab=readme-ov-file) expects. And in my case the real error is "Missing input file"

[image]

If you need comprehensive help - you need to provide at least full [jmeter.log](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) file and preferably with [JMeter debug logging enabled](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-logging) for the components you're using.

Ideally you should provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to wit your testplan, your .proto files and your backend in form of i.e. Docker image if it's not publicly available.

Comment: my .proto : 
syntax = "proto3";

option csharp_namespace = "GRPCDocker";

package greet;

// The greeting service definition.
service Greeter {
  // Sends a greeting
  rpc SayHello (HelloRequest) returns (HelloReply);
}

// The request message containing the user's name.
message HelloRequest {
  string name = 1;
}

// The response message containing the greetings.
message HelloReply {
  string message = 1;
}

Comment: Log stack : 2024-03-12 17:54:40,724 ERROR v.z.b.GRPCSamplerGui: Proto folder path is empty. Please select your proto folder
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve service by invoking protoc


2024-03-12 17:54:40,724 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: Uncaught exception in thread Thread[AWT-EventQueue-0,6,main]
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve service by invoking protoc


Caused by: vn.zalopay.benchmark.exception.ProtocInvocationException: Unable to execute protoc binary

Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Unsupported platform: protoc-3.21.4-windows-x86_32.exe     @Ivan G